# Making a curl request with headers in apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

I am trying to make a curl request using apps script, the link of the official guide of which is below. Here is the query:

```
curl -X POST "https://bhagavadgita.io/auth/oauth/token" -H "accept: application/json" -H "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -d "client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=verse"
```

According to the official guide:

> How to get an access token? 
>   
> Make a POST request to /auth/oauth/token with these parameters sent in Headers -
>   
> Client ID - Obtained from Account Dashboard after registering an app.
>   
> Client Secret - Obtained from Account Dashboard after registering an app.
>   
> Grant Type - Use client credentials.
>   
> Scope - Use verse if you just want to access the verses, chapter if you just want to access the chapters and verse chapter if you want access to both.

I have written the code as below:

```
function myFunction() {

var data = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'content-type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'header':{
              'client_id':'MY-CLIENT-ID',
              'client_secret':'MY-CLIENT-SECRET',
              'grant_type':'client_credentials',
              'scope':'verse'
    }

};

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://bhagavadgita.io/auth/oauth/token', data);
Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

I am getting an error as below:

```
Exception: Request failed for https://bhagavadgita.io returned code 405. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN"> <title>405 Method Not Allowed</title> <h1>Method Not Allowed</h1> <p>The method is not allo... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 13, file "Code")
```

What is the proper way of making such a request?

**Reference:** https://bhagavadgita.io/api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`405` error is stating that you cannot query that endpoint with the current HTTP verb.

You should specify that your `.fetch` method is making a `POST` Http request.

To do so you have to specify in the `"method" : "post"` parameter in your fetch options:

```
var data = {
    'client_id':'MY-CLIENT-ID',
    'client_secret':'MY-CLIENT-SECRET',
    'grant_type':'client_credentials',
    'scope':'verse'
}

var options = {
  "method" : "post",
  "accept": "application/json",
  "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  "payload" : data
}

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://bhagavadgita.io/auth/oauth/token', options);
```

### References:

[UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app)

[REST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that you were specifying the headers in the payload. Now it should work.